# Использование С++ библиотеки в C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, wpf

Всем привет! Народ, подскажите, может, кто сталкивался с таким.

1. Есть библиотека на C++ .lib, есть API к ней, в виде заголовочных файлов.
2. Есть пример использования API на С++
3. Есть WPF-приложение на C#, в котором необходимо использовать эту библиотеку.

Как это наиболее удобно сделать? C++, к сожалению, не знаю совершенно.. :(

1. Основной класс из библиотеки, с которым надо работать (заголовочный файл):

   ```
   class ManagerWindows: public Manager 
   {
   public:
       static std::shared_ptr<ManagerWindows> getInstance();
   };
   ```
2. Вот пример вызова этого класса :

   ```
   std::shared_ptr<ManagerWindows> manager_;

   manager_ = ManagerWindows::getInstance();
   ```

Не знаю даже, с какой стороны подступиться...

Попытался написать CLR-враппер:

```
//library.h
namespace Library {

    public ref class Wrapper
    {
    public:
        std::shared_ptr<ManagerWindows> getInstance();
    };
}

//library.cpp
std::shared_ptr<ManagerWindows> Library::Wrapper::getInstance()
{
    return ManagerWindows::getInstance();
}
```

При попытке использования из С# такая ошибка компиляции:

```
        Wrapper mw;
        mw = new Wrapper();
        object o = mw.getInstance();
```

Error   CS0570  'Wrapper.getInstance(?)' is not supported by the language

Comment: Ну, напишите управляемую обёртку на C++/CLI. Для этого, возможно, вам понадобится толковый программист, который знает как C++, так и .NET.

Comment: А что делает эта библиотека? Судя по названию классов, она рисует UI? Если так, то намного проще написать свой UI на WPF.

Comment: Библиотека бля работы с устройством

Comment: Тогда нужна обёртка, да.

Comment: @VladD, а зачем нужна обертка? Разве нельзя все просто, через P/invoke сделать?

Comment: @iluxa1810, с классами P/invoke не особо

Comment: @iluxa1810: P/Invoke позволяет вызывать сишные функции, а функции и классы C++ уже не так просто, если вообще возможно.

Comment: Я тоже склоняюсь к врапперу C++/CLI, потому как вызывать надо именно классы...
Может, есть у кого пример реализации подобного враппера?

Comment: @Maxiero, [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235281.aspx): найдется все :)